# An example for a wise witch or wizard from Ravenclaw

Tags: harry-potter

We all know that Ravenclaw depicts wisdom. However three wise people in the stories (Albus Dumbledore, Minerva McGonagall and Hermione Granger) have come from Gryffindor. Thus, it makes me wonder if there was anyone mentioned in the stories who actually belonged to Ravenclaw and was as wise as them?

Comment: Ravenclaw is more scholarly talent, of which we see several examples.

Comment: Ravenclaws are more like bookworms. Their wisdom is limited to "books-only".

Comment: The story doesn't focus on Ravenclaw and Huflepuff houses much so we dont have that much to work with here. I got the impression that professor Flitwick is as talented and professional as Minerva McGonagall, but we dont see much of him.  Also, Dumbledore tends to select his pawns from people he knows well and trusts and many of those seem to hail from Gryffindor house. Other houses have less opportunity to 'shine' in the HP books.

Comment: If someone in Ravenclaw is as wise as them.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (possibly Pottermore) that both McGonagall and Flitwick were close to hat-stalls, both being split between Gryffindor and Ravenclaw. This implies to me that they both could easily have fit in either house if they wanted.

Comment: I think this is Primarily Opinion Based unless the question provides criteria to be used for determining who is "wise" (e.g. that the person is described as "wise" in the books).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Ravenclaw mean by being clever?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195832/what-does-ravenclaw-mean-by-being-clever)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to remember a very important factor of the house sorting which is often overlooked - you aren't put in a house just because of your natural talents. A lot of it has to do with how you regard the specific traits associated with each house.

Hermione for example is easily smart enough to be put in Ravenclaw, but in the very first book we see what she thinks of Gryffindor's traits:

> "Me!" said Hermione. "Books! And cleverness! There are more important things – friendship and bravery ...

Hermione sees bravery as being more important than intelligence, so she fit into Gryffindor. Likewise we have the example of Peter Pettigrew, who was to all intents and purposes a coward - but looked up to people with strength. He didn't fit the Gryffindor mantra whatsoever.

I can imagine a lot of Ravenclaws simply appreciate intelligence and strive to be their best, whether or not they have a natural talent for it. Whereas some of the smartest people in the books - such as Dumbledore and McGonagall, as you've mentioned - simply value other things.

Now, to answer your question - there's a handy [list of known Ravenclaws](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ravenclaw#Known_Ravenclaws) at the Harry Potter wiki. Probably the most notable one here would be Olivander - he's well-known in the UK at least as being the best wandmaker around, and we know that wandlore is an extremely complex branch of magic. That must surely show a very high level of intelligence - he's a theoretical physicist of the magical world.